# How to receive and send form data in Django to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

I'm trying to make Django receive data from a form, then process it and output it into JavaScript.

I've tried to follow Django's tutorial on making a form and it seems to work, however when I click the submit button I simply get transfered to http://127.0.0.1:8000/your-name/. I suppose i have to do something in views but I'm not entirely sure what exactly.

**How do I process the data and send it to JS?**

**HTML**

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import NameForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == "POST":
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print("yesss")
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/thanks/")

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, "index.html", {"form": form})
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms


class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label="Your name", max_length=100)
```

Comment: Try looking at [How to pass data to javascript in Django Framework?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pass-data-to-javascript-in-django-framework/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    console.group("Index.djt logs")
    
    // collect all data supplied by DJANGO into this object
    const DJANGO_DATA = {}

    // all CAPITAL CASE variables will be used in index.js js which are given by django server
    const DEVICE_IDS = {{device_ids | safe}}
    const DEVICE_HANDSHAKE_TIMES = {}

    // urls which are supplied by django server
    const CLEAR_WIFI = "{% url 'iot_control:clear_wifi' %}"
    const ADD_DEVICE = "{% url 'iot_control:add_device' %}"
    const POWER_CONSUMPTION = "{% url 'iot_control:power_consumption' %}"

    const CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token }}'
    var POWER_SUPPLY = "{{power_supply}}" == "True"?true:false;
    var device_ids = DEVICE_IDS.join(','); // just for selenium testing
    // only `var` type variables are accessed by selenium


    const switch_data = {{switch_data | safe}}
    let timezone = null
</script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

you can use all the data in page javascript by accessing `DJANGO_DATA` variable if you are integrating typescript you can follow the below procedure

```
import $ from "jquery";
import {DeviceTimers, PowerStates, DjangoDataInterface} from "./types"

declare const DJANGO_DATA: DjangoDataInterface;
```

this `DJANGO_DATA` typescript variable will be populated by script tag which is attached before this one